# Observable data service, subscribe not called

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-observables

I want to create a reactive store for a user object. So let me first describe what I have tried. I defined a simple user class:

```
export class User {
  constructor(public $key: string) {}
}
```

For simplicity the class just contains a key. I use firebase storage and to query this storage I created a service class:

```
export class UserService {

  constructor(private af: AngularFire, private authService: AuthService) {}

  getUser() {
    return this.authService.authInfo$.concatMap(a => this.af.database.object('/users/' + a.uid));
  }
}
```

`getUser()` first fetches the user id and queries the firebase database for the specific user. However I don't want to use the service directly. Rather I would like to have a global store that has a BehaviorSubject, which contains the latest user object. So lets introduce the store:

```
export class UserStore {

  private _user: BehaviorSubject<User> = new BehaviorSubject(null);

  constructor(private userService: UserService) {
    this.userService.getUser().subscribe(
      userJson => {
        this._user.next(new User(userJson.$key, userJson.firstName, userJson.lastName, null, userJson.personalDataSheet));
      },
      err => console.error
    );
  }

  get user() {
    return this._user.asObservable();
  }
}
```

Now I use this store in a component like this:

```
this.userStore.user.subscribe(
  user => console.log(user)
);
```

And it works! The user is logged. However when I do something like

```
user: User;
...
this.userStore.user.subscribe(
  user => this.user = user
);
```

subscribe will be called just once with the user being null. Why is that? Does `this.user = user` create some kind of another subscription and cancels the first one?

Comment: and what makes you say that user is not updated again? Did you try logging and assigning both?

Comment: @MadhuRanjan right, as I log user and it is logged just once (null)

Comment: Can you create a Plunker with your issue? I tried it but not getting any issue, check this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/6uAA6q57v7Vf8Y4ZdR6C?p=preview), for example sake i just used `Observable.interval`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that **at least two different values** are being emitted by your BehaviorSubject:

- `null` — Initial value you provided when instantiating the subject.
- `User` instance — Value emitted as soon as the Firebase call returns.
- [Optionally] Modified `User` instance — Since everything is "live" with Firebase, your subject could potentially keep emitting different instances for the current user (for example, you'd get a new value if the user logged out).

So, depending on the point of execution of your `.subscribe()` you might end up getting the `null` value.

I would try to use a ReplaySubject instead. A ReplaySubject *only starts emitting once a value is explicitly pushed into it*. This means you can get rid of that initial `null` value and as long as Firebase hasn't returned, the user won't be available (= the subscribe will be "waiting").

More specifically, here's the line I'd change:

```ts
private _user: ReplaySubject<User> = new ReplaySubject<User>(1);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So BehaviorSubject is used to provide a initial value and a stream of values over time. This works great for e.g. a list, which is empty in the beginning. But for an object it does not really make sense to have a initial value right? So considering this you would suggest to use ReplaySubject?

Comment: Exactly! Actually you could still use a `ReplaySubject` to provide values over time. What sets it apart from the BehaviorSubject is that you can adjust the "buffer size", ie the number of values it can replay. But in your example, you're not using the ReplaySubject for this feature (you only ever want to "replay" ONE value) but for the fact that it doesn't start emitting a default value right away.